# How can I set the date format in CKAN Data Explorer?

Tags: ckan

I have a CKAN site with DataStore, DataPusher and Data Explorer configured and running. 
I uploaded a csv file with a date column in DD-MM-YYYY format to my CKAN site and the DataStore determined its type as 'timestamp'. However, when I preview the contents of the file, the date field is presented in the YYYY-MM-DD format, messing with the sorting and filtering features. 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without modifying the source code (either directly or via an extension), and there is no single/simple place where the code is explicitly formatting the date so that you could easily intervene. I would intervene here:
https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckanext/reclineview/theme/public/recline_view.js#L91

By looking inside the dataset for timestamp columns and then reformatting the value with e.g. moment.js.

By the way, the CKAN team are working on an improved data viewer which might have better scope for configurability:
https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3444